# How should I implement an Auth handler that takes effect on response?

Tags: python-requests, keycloak

I wish to implement an Auth handler for requests that handles authentication with an OAuth Authorization server to allow the following:

```
import requests

requests.get(url, auth=KeycloakAuth())
```

What I've done so far is to apply a response hook when KeycloakAuth is called, so that when the client redirects the caller to Keycloak, the hook will see the Keycloak login page, post the credentials to Keycloak and get redirected back to the client.

However, this does not work for a POST, as requests makes a POST to Keycloak's login page instead of a GET due to the redirect. Keycloak doesn't return the login form in response to a POST and this fails.

I considered checking for the redirect in the response hook so that I can modify the redirect to do a GET to Keycloak instead, but it seems like requests' implementation of redirects bypasses all the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

After poking into this a bit more, I believe this may be the wrong question to ask.

I was seeking a solution where, regardless of the original HTTP method used on the client (GET, POST, HEAD, etc), the library would automatically login to Keycloak, and then "replay" the original request to the client and make it effectively transparent to the user of the library.

However, this can't possibly work with OAuth 2.0 without further state management on either the part of the library or the client, due to the redirecting.

Suppose the original request was a POST, with some data. After finding that the user is not logged in, the User-Agent will be redirected to the Authorization Server for authentication.

This means that the original request's POST data will be lost, removing the opportunity for any replay, upon the User-Agent being redirected back to the client after authentication.

With some state management, the POST data could be stored for replay - it doesn't make sense to store the data on the server side since the data could be arbitrarily large, which leaves us with the user of the library to do the state management.

However, that amount of state management should probably not belong in a library, since the library will have to handle lots of cases to guarantee only-once delivery of the request, for example, which would be expected by the user of the requests library.

As such, this Auth handler is probably not something we can implement in a library.